# @objc protocol crashes the swift compiler

Tags: ios, swift, ios7

I wrote I protocol which was intended to have some `@optional` methods, but the swift compiler crashes. This works:

```
protocol SessionDelegate {

    // TODO these should all be optional
    func willOpenSession(session: Session);
    func didOpenSession(session: Session);
    func didFailOpenningSession(session: Session, error: NSError!);

    func willCloseSession(session: Session);
    func didCloseSession(session: Session);
}
```

This doesn't:

```
@objc protocol SessionDelegate {

    @optional func willOpenSession(session: Session);
    @optional func didOpenSession(session: Session);
    @optional func didFailOpenningSession(session: Session, error: NSError!);

    @optional func willCloseSession(session: Session);
    @optional func didCloseSession(session: Session);
}
```

Honestly, having `@objc` is enough to crash the compiler. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Does your protocol have to extend the NSObject protocol?

Comment: Hey, do you have `Session` declared as a subclass of `NSObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your only way around this is to declare the protocol in an Objective-C header file and import the declaration via an Objective-C bridging header.

**Protocol declaration:**

```
// SessionDelegate.h

@class Session;

@protocol SessionDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void)willOpenSession:(Session *)session;
- (void)didOpenSession:(Session *)session;
- (void)didFailOpenningSession:(Session *)session error:(NSError *)error;

- (void)willCloseSession:(Session *)session;
- (void)didCloseSession:(Session *)session;

@end
```

**Bridging header:**

```
// MyProject-Bridging-Header.h

#import "SessionDelegate.h"
```

**Conforming class implementation in Swift:**

```
// Session.swift

class Session {
    // ...
}

class MySessionDelegate: NSObject, SessionDelegate {
    func willOpenSession(session: Session) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm !! I never got to learn objective-c, so thanks for the code ;)

Comment: Could you please see my other question? It's related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591921/sessiondelegate-does-not-have-a-member-named-xxx

Answer (score 1):

Apology, scratch my previous edit, try following instead:

```
@objc(PSessionDelegate)
protocol PSessionDelegate {

    @optional func willOpenSession(session: Session);
    @optional func didOpenSession(session: Session);
    @optional func didFailOpenningSession(session: Session, error: NSError!);
    @optional func willCloseSession(session: Session);
    @optional func didCloseSession(session: Session);

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, PSessionDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: No. I'm just trying to make the protocol methods optional. Pure swift, nothing in objective-c.

Comment: @André Fratelli, the code is tested on iOS 7.1 device, it did not crash, interesting thing is that your code did not crash neither.

Comment: My code crashes the compiler, so it doesn't get to iOS... I'll try your answer because it's in swift, although @Nate Cook's solution already worked =)

Comment: Go figure, it does work ! But why? What difference does it make to have @objc(PSessionDelegate) instead of just @objc ?

Comment: Scratch that... It didn't work when I had the class conform with the protocol. The compiler crashes.

Comment: @André Fratelli, it did not make difference since you are not exposing it to Objective C code, I suspect somewhere else in your code crashed.

Comment: @André Fratelli, if you create a new class, and conform with the protocol, does that crash?

Comment: yes it does. I'm not sure that I made clear that this crashes at compile time. The compiler crashes, the app never gets to run. So it would hardly be because of the code. If I don't use objc or use Nate Cook's approach, everything works fine.

Comment: @André Fratelli, it looks freaky, why not try create a fresh new project and try that? (Granted if you are interested in finding out why compiler crashes. I couldn't at all understand why '@obj' and '@optional' could cause compiler crash.)

Comment: Xcode is still beta, so it doesn't surprise me all that much. It's not an option to create a new project.

Comment: The Objective-C version is just a workaround until the bugs in Swift and Xcode 6 are squashed - the second code block @AndréFratelli posted is fine (other than the crashing Xcode thing).

Comment: @Nate Cook, it looks you are having the same Xcode crash, can you post the crash log?

Comment: It's odd then... My xcode about box indicates Xcode 6.0 (6A215l), what about yours?

Comment: Apple has updated to Xcode 6 beta 2 (6A216f) - you should get that!